# Using Windows Word macro in Mac Word

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have written a macro (assigned to a button) in Word in Windows, and I want to use it in Word in Mac, however, the button is not working in Mac anymore, and I have to run the macro from the Visual Basic editor. Any hints?

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Style = "Style2"

        iCount = 0
        While .Execute
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Wend

        MsgBox (iCount)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveX controls are not supported by Microsoft Office for MAC. Try assigning the macro to some other object.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot link a macro to a button in Word for Mac. The button object only exists in UserForms- not directly in the Word Document. (Oddly enough, it does exist in Excel.) This has been a major frustration for me as I want to allow the users to kick off a script easily without visiting the "macros" area. You can access macros from from the Menu item: Tools -> Macro -> Macros, or the View ribbon in 2016.

Note: to make that available to the Macros area, you have to make it Public.

You can link the macro to a key command, run it from the Macros menu, or have it run on Document_New() or Document_Open().

Here's Microsoft's official way to run a macro in Mac Word (2016). https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Run-a-macro-in-Word-2016-for-Mac-e1407255-84f6-49a0-bb54-56e04bfdec23

Hope this helps.